# Redis SCAN not giving all matches in NodeJS and node_redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using a Node.JS script with the node_redis npm package to retrieve all the Redis keys that match a pattern `animals:toFeed:*`. An example of a match will be the `key animals:toFeed:17ed160f59c5b31caf7e741a4e62cb7785414cd.`
How can I do scan with this package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to reiterate over the returned cursor until it's value is 0.
Remember that SCAN's sole purpose is to work in iterations.

It's not a matter of a specific redis driver/client, you just need to get the cursor value and call the scan command again the cursor is 0.

If you want to (optimistically) have all of the result set return in a single call, specifiy COUNT with a very high value. bear in mind it's never 100% guaranteed you'll the entire result set within a single call.

See the [Redis SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) documentation for an example complete with commands and responses.

Comment: can you give me an example for function and thank you.

Comment: See the [Redis Scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan) documentation for an example complete with commands and responses.